# AWS/EC2/Ubuntu/Nginx - Where is web root?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

I can't seem to find the web root location on a AWS EC2 **Ubuntu** instance with **Nginx** web server. I've tried searching via SSH in terminal and SFTP using FileZilla (pem). I've seen a lot of comments that suggest looking in these directories, but I don't see anything.

```
/var/www/
/etc/apache/
/home/ubuntu/
```

I didn't create this instance so I'm a bit lost. Any advice for an AWS newbie?

Comment: Alright, understood

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding the location by switching to root shell with:

```
sudo -i
find / -name "filename.php"
```

For me, the files were in:

```
/srv/users/mywebsitename/apps/mywebsitename/public
```

Also, I wasn't aware that my question was off-topic. Maybe it can still help someone...